# This old tv show about a kid who solved some ancient puzzles his dad made

Tags: story-identification, tv, animation

I just remember this one part I saw like 15 years ago.
Some kid was solving some ancient cube puzzle (I thought his father made it) in a temple and when he touched it the room locked with bars and he could use animals or something but the room was too small but he had some kind of small monkey who could fit through the bars and help him.

Comment: Was this TV show animated or live action? Do you know if you saw other episodes or just that episode? If the former do you know if the cube or the monkey at least appeared in other episodes?

Comment: @Kodabeertje  Your description seems to contain a paradox.  The protagonist is a "Kid" and thus not yet of adult age.  The puzzle was made by the kid's father, who thus should have been born less than his entire lifetime before the kid was born.  The longest known human lifetime was 120 years.  To me the word "ancient"   implies dating from before the end of Classical Antiquity around AD 500.  Thus your story description contains a paradox unless time travel is involved.